# Edge-based smooth color fill in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient, fill

Is it possible in Photoshop to fill with a smooth color, based on the existing edges of the selected area? Mathematically speaking, I'm looking for a partial differential equation filling, with the edge and 'smooth function' as restrictions.

I would like to remove text from a logo, with a gradient background, [image: as shown in this picture]. The context-aware filling is not working, because is it also considering other parts of the image, which causes structures to be added to the fill.

Can the letters be removed and filled with smooth yellow color, conform to the gradient?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: ...do you have a screenshot? I don't follow what you're trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: added a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Content Aware fill in Photoshop is designed for removing things from photographs, not from gradients in logos. It takes parts of the surrounding image and tries to fill in the selection with similar textures. It's called "Photoshop" for a reason!

I think you are making this more complex than it needs to be.

What I would do is fill over the existing text and background with a new background, and then add new text.

1. Make a selection around the entire area that encompasses the background and text
2. Use the Pen Tool if you want accuracy
3. Turn the path into a selection
4. create a new layer
5. Fill it with a gradient - sampling the existing gradient if necessary to recreate it
6. Add new text

Also I might add that using Photoshop for logo design/editing logos is less than ideal. Logos are best designed using vector image editing software, such as Adobe Illustrator, CorelDraw, or the free software Inkscape.  Recreating a logo in vectors would be the ideal scenario.  The main benefit is that vectors are rescalable without degradation in quality, also editing them is easier.

Using Photoshop for logos is a bit like hammering in a screw in, rather than using a screwdriver. Sure, it'll get the job done if you hit it hard enough, but it's better to use the right tool for the job if you want the best results.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it helped me getting it done. However, does this mean it is not possible to do as asked in the original question with Photoshop?
I have used Inkscape, but vectorizing a logo that contains texture and gradients just doesn't give satisfying results. Is Illustrator better at this?

Comment: Yes it is possible in Photoshop - since my answer was for Photoshop, but in the main, vector editors are better for logos. If you have some elements that require textures and gradients that would be tricky to reproduce in vectors, it is possible to use raster images in both Inkscape/Illustrator - and it's also possible to trace raster images automatically.